# How to Open Lua scripts in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 From a Terminal : Using a ubuntu 14.0.4

Tags: scripting, lua, terminal, ubuntu-14.04, netbeans-8

I want to open lua script file in Netbeans IDE 8.0.2 from terminal using ubuntu 14.0.4

I have follow this commends:

open /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.0\ M2.app/ && /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 7.0\ M2.app/Contents/MacOS/netbeans --open dummy.r

Answer (score 1):

If you install Netbeans via software center, you should find a shell script in /usr/bin/.

You can call the program with the following command:

```
netbeans
```

If that does not work, you have to add the path for Netbeans. Otherwise, you just need to pass the file name:

```
netbeans /pathtofile/file.lua
```